# Is it possible to add/change your profile picture?

Tags: 17.04

I use Ubuntu 17.04 and I was just wondering if it was possible. Thanks for viewing!

Answer (score 5):

Of course. Open the **System Settings**, then open **User Accounts**, select your user and simply click the profile picture. In the pop-up there should be a button to browse for more images if you want that.